# ffmpeg: not found when running ffmpeg via php xampp (mac)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp

I am trying to execute ffmpeg from php. I have installed ffmpeg locally on my mac via homebrew and I am able to run the commands I need via terminal.

When I try to execute the following code:

```
<?php
    echo "Starting ffmpeg";
    $output = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k out.mp3 2>&1");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I am receiving the following on my browser:

> Starting ffmpeg
>
> sh: 1: ffmpeg: not found

I am assuming that I somehow need to install ffmpeg to my xampp server but it is not obvious how to do that. After searching online I can find linux and Windows tutorials but I couldn't figure out something out by looking at them.

What I tried doing was to download the ffmpeg static build form https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac and placed it in the htdocs holder, and then tried to execute ffmpeg as if it was an executable (after changing chmod), but that gave me

> sh: 1: ./ffmpeg: Exec format error

How would one go and install and then run ffmpeg on their xampp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the apache server that xampp starts is a debian instance. I was using the wrong static build (mac instead of debian one). Downloading and using the debian one resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

First check for installation of tha package by "ffmpeg -version"
If it is installed then check for path "whereis ffmpeg", then try your command with full ffmpeg path

Comment: This is odd. 'ffmpeg -version' does return the version (ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)) and then something that looks like configuration commands, but if i do 'whereis ffmpeg' nothing is returned.

Comment: doing a 'which ffmpeg' return a valid path